# Selecting a DBMS for a Java Application

Tags: java, database

I am a beginner in software developement and I would like to know what is the best and simplest DBMS to use with Java. I want to create a simple agenda application to improve my skills in software developement, and i want to store the agenda events and access them easily. I am not sure if a dbms is the easiest way, maybe xml or json would do the trick.
Thanks for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure you want a DBMS, you can use HSQLDB (http://www.hsqldb.org) or Apache Derby (http://db.apache.org) as a simple in-process database.

If you also want to use the opportunity to learn relational databases in general, grab PostgreSQL and use that. It has a very good set of SQL features and is one of the most standard compliant databases out there.

Answer (score 2):

[Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) comes bundled with JDK 1.6 and greater. It is more than sufficient for learning purposes.

Comment: @Zak001 if this answer is what you were looking for then accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

[JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc), the API you'll use to connect your Java application to most databases can be quite frustrating to a beginner.

I strongly recommend using SQLite, it's simple to use, and it's very lightweight.

To connect to a SQLite Database using Java, there are [many options available](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers#java).

For a beginner, however, I recommend using [sqlite4java](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/).

Here's a code sample:

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("/tmp/database"));
    db.open(true);
    ...
    SQLiteStatement st = db.prepare("SELECT order_id FROM orders WHERE quantity >= ?");
    try {
      st.bind(1, minimumQuantity);
      while (st.step()) {
        orders.add(st.columnLong(0));
      }
    } finally {
      st.dispose();
    }
    ...
    db.dispose();
```

But if you want to use JDBC, I don't think the database choice will make much difference, as long as you're using a [Type 4 JDBC Driver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_4_Driver_-_Native-Protocol_Driver).